# How to properly inject dependency into Laravel artisan command?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, laravel, laravel-4, ioc-container

Basically I want to call a method on a repository Repository.php from a laravel command.

```
Example\Storage\Repository.php
Example\Storage\RepositoryInerface.php
Example\Storage\RepositoryServiceProvider.php
```

I expect Interface in the command constructor and then set it to the protected variable.

In the service provider I bind the Interface to Repository class.

Right now, in start/artisan.php I just write:

```
Artisan::add(new ExampleCommand(new Repository());
```

Can I use an interface here? What is the correct way? I am confused.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: To clarify, it only works the way it is now, but I don't want to hardcode a concrete class while registering the artisan command.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use the automatic dependency injection capabiltiies of the IoC container:

```
Artisan::add(App::make('\Example\Commands\ExampleCommand'));
// or
Artisan::resolve('\Example\Commands\ExampleCommand');
```

If ExampleCommand's constructor accepts a concrete class as its parameter, then it'll be injected automatically. If it relies on the interface, you need to tell the IoC container to use a specific concrete class whenever the given interface is requested.

Concrete (ignoring namespaces for brevity):

```
class ExampleCommand ... {
    public function __construct(Repository $repo) {
    }
}

Artisan::resolve('ExampleCommand');
```

Interface (ignoring namespaces for brevity):

```
class ExampleCommand ... {
    public function __construct(RepositoryInterface $repo) {
    }
}

App::instance('RepositoryInterface', new Repository);
Artisan::resolve('ExampleCommand');
```

Comment: The Command constructor accepts Repository interface, the command itself is not in the IoC just the Repository, that I need to inject into command which is located in the default directory.

Comment: What I don't understand is what do I need to change to be able 
`Artisan::add(new ExampleCommand(new Repository());` change to `Artisan::add(new ExampleCommand(new RepositoryInterface());`

Comment: You don't need the command in the IoC container - the IoC container is clever in that if it gets a 'classname' that's not already in the container, it tries to instantiate it *and* its constructor's dependencies. Try my code and see, just make sure you use FQCNs.

Comment: That's really magic. Tried `Artisan::add(App::make('\Example\Commands\ExampleCommand'));` and it works as expected. Where can I read more about it? Could you elaborate please? :)

Comment: It's pretty much explained [in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#automatic-resolution). I think it's kind of a convenient side-effect of automatic resolution that you can `App::make()` any class. The point being that when the IoC container needs to do automatic resolution, all it knows is a constructor's arguments, from that it works out the classes from the hints, and from there it works out how to create instances to pass in. So, rather than creating a protected method for this resolution, Taylor made it part of the `make()` method, so any code can use it, not just the IoC container.

Comment: To update the link to the docs in my above comment, the new "permalink" is https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/ioc#automatic-resolution

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `interface` in the constructor to type hint the depended object but you have to bind the concrete class to the interface in the `IoC` container using something like following, so it'll work.

```
App::bind('Example\Storage\RepositoryInerface', 'Example\Storage\Repository');
```

Read more on the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc#basic-usage).

Comment: Yes I am already doing that in the ServiceProvider, and it works correctly in the Command constructor, but how do I pass the interface `Artisan::add(new ExampleCommand(new Repository());` here?

Comment: You don't need to pass it, `IoC` container will automatically inject the dependencies.

Comment: So I must concrete class here? How is the binding helping me then? If I implement another class using the interface I will need to change the binding + Change it here. What am I missing? Please see my comment on the other answer.